# BibTeX with revtex4-1

Tags: bibtex, revtex

I have tried using the command `\bibliography` for the `.bib` file in `revtex4-1` package. However I can never get the bibliography in the pdf. Moreover, I have also tried using `\nocite{*}` and the commands

```
@CONTROL{REVTEX41Control}
@CONTROL{apsrev41Control,author="08",editor="1",pages="0",title="",year="1"}
```

However, I still can't seem to get the bibliography. And I think I should mention that my document is `onecolumn` in `revtex4-1`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I'm afraid your posting isn't easy to follow at present. Please edit your posting to (a) state more succinctly what you're trying to accomplish and (b) provide a compilable example of what you've tried so far. It doesn't have to be a *working* example.

Comment: Please edit the title of your posting to reflect the determination, arrived at in the meantime, that the issues you're experiencing with BibTeX are in no way related to the use of the `revtex4-1` document class. Indeed, the title and the body of the posting should now clearly reflect the fact that the issue appears to be related to the nonavailability of a certain bibliography style on your system.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it turns out that the OP's issue is not at all related to anything mentioned in the posting. Instead, it was related to an attempt to load a nonexisting bibliography style file.

Answer (score 1):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

Creating a formatted bibliography and citation call-outs to entries listed in the bibliography is no different in the `revtex4-1` document class than it is in other document classes.

- For sure, you need to provide a `bibliographystyle` directive -- the style may well be dictated by the journal to which you're contemplating submitting your paper to, one or more `\cite` directives, and a `\bibliography` statement, whose argument should be a list of or or more bib files.
- Assuming there are no syntax errors in the bib file, running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on the main tex file should produce (a) a formatted bibliography and (b) proper citation call-outs to the items in the bibliography.

[image]$

In the preceding screenshot, `[1]` is a numeric-style citation call-out. Why is the style numeric? It's because the `plain` bibliography style is in use in the example, and that particular bibliography style produces only numeric-style citation call-outs.

Note that the code succeeds in creating a bibliography without any `@CONTROL` statements.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{aa:3001,
  author  = "Anne Author",
  title   = "Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 3001,
  volume  = 1,
  number  = 2, 
  pages   = "3--4",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[onecolumn]{revtex4-1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\cite{aa:3001}
\section{Goodbye}

\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried inserting the code about the bib file both in the beginning of the original tex file and as a separate bib file. But neither worked.

Comment: @Souradeep - I'm afraid comments such as "it didn't work" are not sufficiently specific. What exactly did you try? Does your real tex file contain a `\bibliographystyle` directive? If so, which style does it employ? Are the needed bibliographic entries contained in a bib file? Does the argument of `\bibliography` point to this bib file? Does the tex file contain `\cite` instructions? And, did you run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more? If so, are there any error and/or w messages either in the `log`  file (created by LaTeX) or the `blg` file (BibTeX's log file)?  If so, what do they say?

Comment: I'm sorry for the lack of clarity. I didn't use any \bibliographystyle templates. Yes the entries are contained in the bib file. The argument does point to the same file. The tex file doesn't contain any \cite commands and so I used \nocite{*}. And yes I ran all the compilers. No, there aren't any error messages. Thank you again.

Comment: @Souradeep - If no `\bibliographystyle` directive is provided, BibTeX will definitely not know what to do, and hence it won't do anything *except* issue a warning message about no `\bibstyle` directive having been found. Do note that this isn't specific to the `revtex4-1` document class.

Comment: This is the error message I'm getting on using the style aps
I can't find file aps.bst. I'm skipping over the next commands.

Comment: @Souradeep - Are you sure that you're following instructions correctly when you type `\bibliographystyle{aps}`? Should it maybe be either `\bibliographystyle{aipauth4-1}`, `\bibliographystyle{aipnum4-1}`, or possibly even `\bibliographystyle{apsrev}`?

Comment: Thank you so much @Mico. I used apsrev and it helped. However, I can't get any heading for it like references or bibliography. Also there's an ugly horizontal line before the bibliography. Can you please help?? Thank you in advance

Comment: @Souradeep - What you call "an ugly horizontal line before the bibliography" is, in fact, the style imposed by the `revtex4-1` document class (*not* the `apsrev` bibliography style...). If you don't like this "ugly horizontal line", the only suggestion I can offer is to select a different document class. Presumably, though, you're using the `revtex4-1` document class for a reason, right?

Comment: Okay I guess I can make do with the line. But can you please suggest some means to get a heading for the bibliography. It usually appears whenever I use any other style in any other package

Comment: @Souradeep - You asked, "But can you please suggest some means to get a heading for the bibliography." Answer: *I absolutely can not*. The presence of the "ugly horizontal line" and the absence of a sectioning header that says "References" (or something similar) are *both* design features of the `revtex4-1` document class.  If you can't stand its design features, do go ahead and find yourself a document class that suits your personal stylistic preferences better.

Comment: I'm sorry @Mico, I didn't know its full features. Thanks for all the help. Appreciate it.